# MYSQL query help- Substring and Instring

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help writing a query to get some data from a table. I am trying to write a  query that will select all of the book titles that have “bill” in their name and will display the title of the book, the length of the title, and the part of the title that follows “bill”. I know you are supposed to use the substring and instring functions but i keep on running into syntax errors and/or incorrect output

The book table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Book( 
   ISBN        CHAR(13),
   Title       VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
   Description VARCHAR(100),
   Category    INT,
   Edition     CHAR(30),
   PublisherID INT         NOT NULL,
   constraint book_ISBN_pk PRIMARY KEY (ISBN),
   constraint book_category_fk FOREIGN KEY (Category) REFERENCES Category(CatID),
   constraint book_publisherID_fk FOREIGN KEY (PublisherID) REFERENCES Publisher(PublisherID)
);
```

Comment: Does _the part of the title that follows “bill”_ include "bill" itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Standard SQL version, afaik mysql should support those functions, too:

```
select 
   Title
  ,char_length(Title)
  ,substring(Title from position('bill' in Title) + 4)
from book
where Title like '%bill%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp for the match, as follows:

```
select title from books where title regexp '*book*'
```

As for what you're **supposed** to use, in my book, you're only supposed to use what gets the desired result. Optimisation comes later, if ever.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUBSTRING`, `LENGTH` and `INSTR`

```
SELECT
  Title,
  LENGTH(Title) as Length,
  SUBSTRING(Title,INSTR(Title, 'bill'),LENGTH(Title)-INSTR(Title, 'bill')) as Rest
FROM
  Book
WHERE
  Title like '%bill%'
```

[Tested - SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a5d1/8)